# Android calculate rotationY based on view right edge

Tags: android, animation, matrix, matrix-inverse

To get view right edge after rotating it around Y-axis with fixed pivot point I'm using the below code and that is working like it should.

`view.setPivotX(0);
        view.setPivotY(view.getHeight() / 2);
        view.animate().rotationY(rotationAngle).start();
        view.getMatrix().mapRect(rectF);
        int rightEdge = rectF.right;`

Now what I want to do next is to calculate rotationAngle so the right edge of the view will be a specified value (let say 1000px). Any idea how to reach this ?

Comment: Tried to solve it for whole day, but matrix algebra underlying rotationY() is not trivial to inverse. I think it might be better to look for different way to achieve your goal.